Interfacing with 0..-2v Sensor using ADS1115
I'm designing a circuit to interface with a sensor that operates on a ±12VDC power supply and outputs a signal between 0 and -2V. I plan to use an ADS1115 ADC for reading this signal.
Circuit Design:

Would this circuit effectively invert the input signal with a gain of 2?
How precise and stable will the zero-point reading be in this configuration?

Gain approximately of 20k/(10k+1k) ... Offset should be (3 ... 6) mV.

You might want to add a unity gain buffer between sensor and input of this circuit to make the gain independent of the sensor source impedance.
